How do I get a Due Date Tag to display the due date of a form based on the date the user fills in the first field of the form?
I'm working on the homepage of a React app that registers organizations' cyber security intelligence information on a database for a cyber security company. The homepage has three cards that lead to different forms. I want these cards to have tags at the top that show the due date for that section based on when a user fills in the first field of the form. Is there some API for this or do I code it from scratch? If I have to code from scratch, I need help.
I tried searching for solutions online but found nothing.

Please provide some coding context, so that the community will help you.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
